# SQL Agent Job Step Fails. Unable to determine the workspace

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, sql-agent-job

I created a Windows Batch File that performs a get latest to the TFS files.

This code is in the batch file:

```
"D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe" get D:\Project\TFS\Project3X\Core\3.6\trunk\src /force /recursive
```

When I try running the command file manually via cmd, it is working.

But when I run this inside a SQL agent job - CmdExec step, I am getting this error

> Executed as user: CORP\dbbuild. Unable to determine the workspace. You may be able to correct this by running 'tf workspaces /collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl'.

**Should I also install Visual Studio 2012 to get this to work?**

---

Additional Info:

- Microsoft SQL Server Version is 2012
- Microsoft Visual Studio Version is 2010

Comment: Are you sure SQL Server agent is the best tool for doing this?